# Cannot target text element in CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using a very simple free Wordpress theme that I am really happy with but I cannot figure out how to move the names of the budgies along to the right:

http://swearingbudgies.co.uk/

I have tried Firebug to find out how to do this but the only tag I can see is a: - problem is when I apply padding-left to a: it also shunts the images along. Will this require changes to the html/php as well as the CSS to fix?

Comment: u want names below budgies?

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to shift them to the right a bit. I used the solution below to target the correct element so it is all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following class in your CSS. Next time onwards don't come up with site url. Add your problem in fiddle/codepen or something like that and post here your code. Otherwise people will give downvote and close your question including me.

```
a.image_link + div
{
  text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat. I am not sure what you mean about fiddle/codepen - can I put all the code for the whole site in that? I will try that next time so I don't get in trouble!

Comment: not requited hole site code. people want to see only the problematic code. jsfiddle is one of the best place to test your code.

Comment: But the problem is that I didn't know which bit of the code was causing the problem, hence my original question!!!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 #main-content div.post div{
      text-align:right;
    }
```